# What is this? Debian Wheezy, Weird randomly occuring inputs

Tags: linux, debian, vim, login, input

When I login in one of the extra virtual terminals there always come odd signs or control characters between my actual input.
For example I type administrator and after the adm some garbage gets inserted.

Something similar happened just now in a session, I was editing /etc/network/interfaces in vim when I pressed ESC and : there appeared a huge load of 787878787878787878787878.........787878787878787878787878 ending with (propably from the file itself) .255

It seems like some ghost input. I am really tired now because currently every single one of my devices is quirky or always breaks randomly. I spent the last weeks more time fixing stuff than actually doing something I want.

Comment: Do the random character actually enter the file? Do they go away after hitting `<c-l>` or `:redraw!`. What is the TERM variable set to? It might be set wrong.

Comment: I was just raging, gonna calm down a bit with beer and a book. Will update the OP when I checked.

Comment: Do you use a custom config?

Comment: No, I dont use a custom config. Checked configs a myriad times against package defaults. The vim incident never happened again, so I couldnt check redraw and c-l.

Comment: I get wrong signs reliably when I press s and y in a short time or at the same time.

Comment: Did you try with a different keyboard? Maybe an hardware failure masked from the GUI drivers. Does it occur even in the terminal? Does it happens in each of the virtual terminal?

Comment: I cant test it anymore, as I have installed another system on it by now. On Gentoo stable with kernel hardened 3.18 to 4.1 and on Xubuntu something nothing like that happens.